# Loading a local .scpt file in my Swift project causes error

Tags: swift, macos, applescript

I'm testing out a Mac app, trying to load my `hello.scpt` file which is in my Xcode project in the `/scripts` directory

```
# even though it's in the scripts folder, `path` will be nil unless the resource value is "hello"
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "hello", ofType: "scpt")
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
let scriptObject = try? NSUserAppleScriptTask(url: url)
scriptObject?.execute { handler in
     print(handler)
}
```

Error:

> Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file
> “hello.scpt” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to
> view it."
> UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-gidwjssyedvwuyfcncsjkfroqdjp/Build/Products/Debug/myApp.app/Contents/Resources/test.scpt,
> NSLocalizedFailureReason=Script file is not in the application scripts
> folder.})

I tried vadian's response below, creating a folder called `NSApplicationScriptsDirectory` which seems weird. Also tried specifying in the `Info.plist` `NSApplicationScriptsDirectory` as the key and different variants to the `./scripts/` file as the key but no luck here.

This is a simple sandboxed app with a Hello World script that just prints "Hello world" to `stdout`

How can I load this AppleScript in and get it to work without the error?

Thanks!

**Edit:** I've also tried putting it in my `~/Library/Scripts` folder as `hello.scpt` but that doesn't work either

Comment: `NSApplicationScriptsDirectory` is an `NSSearchPathDirectory` enumeration for the application’s user scripts folder, i.e. __~/Library/Application Scripts/<code-signing-id>__.

Comment: Thanks @red_menace. I just added the script under the directory `~/Library/Application Scripts/com.zackshapiro.myApp` but still get the same error

Comment: `NSUserAppleScriptTask` is intended to run _user-supplied_ AppleScripts from your application, not scripts built into an application.  See the link in vadian's answer.

Comment: Yep, I get that. And I've been reading through the documentation but something doesn't seem to be working still. I'm just trying to run a script that I wrote, that writes a simple "hello world" to `stdout`. I'd love some help in making that work. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty clear:

> Script file is not in the application scripts folder

---

From the [documentation of NSUserAppleScriptTask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserapplescripttask?changes=_5)

> The `NSUserAppleScriptTask` class is intended to run AppleScript scripts from your application. It is intended to execute user-supplied scripts and will execute them outside of the application's sandbox, if any.
>
> The class is not intended to execute scripts built into an application; for that, use one of the NSTask classes. **If the application is sandboxed, then the script must be in the `NSApplicationScriptsDirectory` folder**. A sandboxed application may read from, but not write to, this folder.
>
> If you simply need to execute scripts without regard to input or output, use `NSUserScriptTask`, which can execute any of the specific types. If you need specific control over the input to or output from the script, use this class.

Comment: Also, if your app is not sandboxed, running a scpt inside your app bundle may still invalidate the codesigning of your app because the script will likely get modified when run (don't ask me why, it's an AppleScript thing).